# Pass class's variable as argument

Tags: java, android, class, variables

I am working on Android Studio, and I want to accomplish the following:

I have this class with some variables:

```
class test {
   private String prop1;
   private int prop2;
   private boolean prop3;
}
```

I want to create a 'generic' method which can change some variable to a new value, like:

```
public changeVar(Variable var, Value val) {
    this.var = val;
}
```

I was wondering if there is any clever way of doing that without the need to make tens of set methods for each variable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just tired to write (or generate) getters/setter for your code and/or do not like to have that getter/setter stuff boilerplating your code then I would recommend to check some external tool like [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/setup/android), see especially annotations [@Getter&@Setter](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter). For [Android Studio](https://projectlombok.org/setup/android).

See also [Is it safe to use Project Lombok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852091/is-it-safe-to-use-project-lombok)

If you really want to make it as you suggest then the answer might be `reflection`. There are some posts about it in SO, like:

[Java, set field value with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094871/java-set-field-value-with-reflection)

[java reflection nested object set private field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110327/java-reflection-nested-object-set-private-field)

But: I am not too so sure if it is *clever* to do it using reflection. It could obfuscate things a lot.